Beamer not recognising \item as a control sequence - Overleaf
I am relatively new to LaTeX, I've used it for formatting documents/writing papers but nothing particularly complex, and I'm now trying to make a poster using it. I'm working on Overleaf online editor.
When I try to compile (this is the document in its entirety):
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=59.4,height=84.1,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}

It throws the error:
Undefined control sequence.
The compiler is having trouble understanding a command you have used. Check that the command is spelled correctly. If the command is part of a package, make sure you have included the package in your preamble using \usepackage{...}.
Learn more

\\itemize ...ix item}##1}}}}} \fi \beamer@cramped 
                                                  \raggedright \beamer@first...
l.6         \item
                test
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/lmss/m/it' in size <24.88> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/lmss/m/it' in size <20.74> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 6.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `TU/lmss/m/it' in size <17.28> not available
(Font)              Font shape `TU/lmss/m/sl' tried instead on input line 6.
[1

I have no idea why it's doing this. I have tried compiling on LaTeX, pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX. Any help would be much appreciated.

You need to place the content of your poster in a frame environment:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,width=59.4,height=84.1,scale=1.0]{beamerposter}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item test
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

